# How to insert numbers into a circular array with skipping some numbers?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

A key used in a cipher is initialized using a dynamic circular array, whose size automatically resizes to the number of values currently present in the array. The input to the cipher is in the form of a stream. 
Every value is added after skipping x places in the array after adding the preceding value as shown below.

> Example: If a circular array 1234382 is given with skip value x is 2,
>   and 8 was just added, the next value 9, will be added as follows
>   19234382 (Elements 2 and 1 are skipped).

**Sample Input-**

```
1
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

**Sample Output -**

```
1
```

**Explanation -**

- The first value 1 is added.
- The next value to be added is 2, which is added after skipping 1 value, which is 1, resulting in 12.
- 3 is then added after skipping 1 (one value from 2), resulting in 132.
- 4 is added after skipping 2 (one value from 3), resulting in 1324.
- 5 is then added after skipping 1 (one value from 4), resulting in 15324 (5 is added just after 1)

Comment: So you just keep track of the last index, add the skip to it, apply modulo arraylength to it so you stay within range, and insert it at that spot.

Comment: Why is the output 1? Did you mean that is the **input** of the `skip` parameter? Should the output be the circular array? Could you also add your attempt and tell us where you are stuck?

Comment: In the one-but-last phrase you mention "skipping 2". Shouldn't that be "skipping 1"?

Comment: No it will be skipping 2 only. @trincot

Comment: Ah, you refer to the *value* in the array, not the `skip` parameter. I see. Can you answer my earlier questions too?

Comment: The output will be 1 since 5 i.e. the last element is added after 1. @trincot

Comment: OK, you never explained the expected output in your question. Could you edit, and add that? Now if the array ends up with duplicate values (like more than one "1"), is the output of 1 then not ambiguous? Also, where in the example do you get the info that that skip parameter is 1? Could you also add your attempt and tell us where you are stuck?

Comment: We are getting skip in the first line of input i.e. 1. I'm not able to generate the correct array. @trincot

Comment: Could your please share your code and tell us *where* in that code you are stuck? Could you also *edit* your question to add the missing information we discussed above?

Comment: As there is no sign of any effort to solve the problem, I think this question should be closed. The Stack Overflow community is willing to help in case of programming problems, but they are not keen on just doing the coding for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: for each iteration in your example, after the first element is inserted, write down the current length of the array and the (zero-based) index where the next insertion will be. Think how the modulus operator might be used.

(Code at ideone.com/Qyk472 that seems to match the example.)